# Transforming / Evaluating (Probably) Normal Data from Sample with Linear Probability Distribution

Tags: dataset, linear-model, model

I have a sample of data for which the count of a given value increases roughly in proportion to the actual value.  For example, the value 22 will occur around 22 times and the value 30 will occur around 30 times.  If I recall this is what is described by a linear probability model.  However, I am almost certain that the underlying distribution is normal, and that the issue is with the sample that has been provided.  Unfortunately, there is no easy way to change this sample, and any suggestions that involve a new sample should be considered a last resort.  Is there a way to use intuition about the data's underlying distribution to model the sample?  Are there known methods to handle this sort of problem?

Comment: Would the value of 1,000,000 occur 1,000,000 times?

Comment: @Aksakal I would probably say not.  In fact, I would like to guess that the trend will decrease leading to a relatively normal distribution, but the sample I have says nothing about this, it is just my intuition.  Is there a way to treat this like a normal distribution despite the lack of data?

Comment: this is a very important detail. What is the support of your probability distribution? Are the values like 1,000,000 even allowed?

Comment: @Aksakal I would not allow them, because the nature of the data means that it would be highly unlikely for the value to exceed 70.  I suppose what I should have said (I'll edit the question) is that I would like to find a way to deal with the fact that the sample is relatively linear despite the underlying distribution likely being normal.

Comment: If your sample is very different from population, then you can't do much with it. I think a better way to approach it is through conditional distribution. Maybe you have some sort of constraint on your measurements, so that your sample conditional on this constraint will have a distribution, which is not normal. You should model this distribution directly. Think of truncated normal distribution, it's based on Gaussian PDF, but it has its own PDF.